# Paypal / Magento Error: This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card

Tags: magento, paypal

I have a web store with Magento 2 installed. For payment methods, I am using PayPal All-in-One Payment solution which is linked with my business Paypal account.

[image]

When a customer completes checkout and selects this payment method, they are redirected to Paypal which displays the following error:

```
This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card.
```

Not sure why this is happening, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have PRO account? I can see there " Website Payments PRO Hosted Solution and Express Checkout ". Seems that you need PRO account there

Answer (score 0):

You can test ist your paypal with sandbox credential, if it is working there is no problem in coding  then  check your paypal live credential and check again if problem is still arrive then you need to contact with paypal support.